# Получение текста с сайта Python

Tags: html, python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить данный текст с сайта? (См. Картинку (Это пример))

Весь день пытался получить текст с другого сайта, ничего не получалось (Использовал всевозможные библиотеки). Помогите, пожалуйста

(Просто подскажите библиотеку, с которой это точно сделать возможно)

Comment: покажите код с вашими попытками. пока это выглядит будто вы желаете спихнуть свою работу на других

Comment: Я удалял тот кусок кода, который не работал

Comment: ну так вы именно так и поступаете. код ваш где?

Comment: Хауди хо рекомендовал - Beautiful Soup К статье его топ библиотек - https://youtu.be/wLIlSYIrr-g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание с avito? Пожалуйста...

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/moskva/sobaki/sobaka_1946261539' # Ваш 2х месячный щенок
resp = requests.get(url)


def get_description(soup):
    result = []
    # Находим все элементы div с классом item-description-text
    ds = soup.findAll('div', class_='item-description-text')
    # Перебираем такие дивы (Скорее всего он будет один, но кто его знает...)
    for d in ds:
        # Так же перебираем все параграфы и заполняем result их значениями
        for p in d.findAll('p'):
            result.append(p.text)

    # Джойним все в одну строку
    return ' '.join(result)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
desc = get_description(soup)
print(desc)
```

Может еще загружать фотки, да не вопрос...

```py
import requests
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/moskva/sobaki/sobaka_1946261539'
resp = requests.get(url)

class RandomNameGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    def generate(self, extension):
        self.t += 1
        return hex(self.t) + extension

# Получаем ссылки на изображения
def get_images_src(soup):
    result = []
    frames = soup.findAll("div", class_="gallery-img-frame")
    for frame in frames:
        if 'data-url' in frame.attrs:
            image = frame.attrs['data-url']
            result.append(image)

    return result

# Скачиваем изображения по ссылкам
def download(link, directory, rng):
    r = requests.get("https:" + link, allow_redirects=True)

    os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
    _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(link)
    filename = rng.generate(file_extension)
    filepath = directory + filename
    open(filepath, 'wb').write(r.content)
    return filepath

rng = RandomNameGenerator()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
images = get_images_src(soup)

for image in images:
    fp = download(image, "./avito_img/", rng)
    print(fp)
```